# Undefined Symbol when building in Xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I have recently got this problem when building for IOS. First time I got it I was able to restore an old version from Plastic backup and then restore each version until recent and the problem was gone. Now that does not work.

I have been googling a lot but do not understand how to solve this problem and would appreciate some help.

I also have not found a description what *U3CPrivateImplementationDetailsU3E* ... is.

The errors is:

> Undefined symbol: _U3CPrivateImplementationDetailsU3E_tBAB6DC40B1709E21296656960228A17F1BE57FD7____499E4F5C84E20C7347E10100E0EC90C1945EA21C7C80809E4F7F474179B39DF6_12_FieldInfo_var

and

> Undefined symbol: _U3CPrivateImplementationDetailsU3E_tBAB6DC40B1709E21296656960228A17F1BE57FD7____9DA6B2C4638D1DC7611B7F458BBFE7FD49FE1B36B67239B00B8A051F4E49558F_22_FieldInfo_var

Here is the Xcode log screenshot with the error part also in text below:

[image]

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_U3CPrivateImplementationDetailsU3E_tBAB6DC40B1709E21296656960228A17F1BE57FD7____499E4F5C84E20C7347E10100E0EC90C1945EA21C7C80809E4F7F474179B39DF6_12_FieldInfo_var", referenced from:
  _Parser__cctor_m56CB9BAD206C2D94D0AC23E6E618F2AD736051E9 in libGameAssembly.a(hfu1rd9b20qx.o)
       "_U3CPrivateImplementationDetailsU3E_tBAB6DC40B1709E21296656960228A17F1BE57FD7____9DA6B2C4638D1DC7611B7F458BBFE7FD49FE1B36B67239B00B8A051F4E49558F_22_FieldInfo_var", referenced from:
  _XsdDateTime__cctor_m4F12859B35713836F38CE50985C1492A7EC4D441 in libGameAssembly.a(hfu1rd9b20qx.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Undefined symbol: _U3CPrivateImplementationDetailsU3E_tBAB6DC40B1709E21296656960228A17F1BE57FD7____499E4F5C84E20C7347E10100E0EC90C1945EA21C7C80809E4F7F474179B39DF6_12_FieldInfo_var

Undefined symbol: _U3CPrivateImplementationDetailsU3E_tBAB6DC40B1709E21296656960228A17F1BE57FD7____9DA6B2C4638D1DC7611B7F458BBFE7FD49FE1B36B67239B00B8A051F4E49558F_22_FieldInfo_var


Build target Unity-iPhone of project Unity-iPhone with configuration ReleaseForRunning
/Users/xxxx/Dropbox/Unity3D/_CONTENT/MyApp/ExecutableIOS/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj: warning: Building with bitcode is deprecated. Please update your project and/or target settings to disable bitcode. (in target 'Unity-iPhone' from project 'Unity-iPhone')


/Users/xxxx/Dropbox/Unity3D/_CONTENT/MyApp/ExecutableIOS/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj: Building with bitcode is deprecated. Please update your project and/or target settings to disable bitcode.
```

**UPDATE**
I deleted Unity executable folder and it seems to solve the problem. However, anyone knows what the problem is?